# Response over time graph becomes very congested for larger number of URLs

Tags: jmeter, response, jmeter-plugins

I am using this https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ResponseTimesOverTime/ plugin.

I already have a .jtl file, I need to browse this .jtl file into the graph plugin and it would display results.

The .jtl file consists of approx ~ 1500 unique URLs and so graph looks so congested that nothing is visible.

Is there an alternative Response over Time graph? or

I can use the same plugin correctly?

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of any existing plugin which can smoothly display 1500 lines with legend on a single chart. Theoretically you can try out [HTML Reporting Dashboard](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html) which provides:

> Zoomable chart where you can check/uncheck every transaction to show/hide it for:
>   Response times Over Time (Includes Transaction Controller Sample Results)

But I strongly doubt it will be a good solution for such a number of unique sample results.

So I would recommend decreasing the number of URLs in your report, you can group them using [Transaction Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Transaction_Controller) and name the controller accordingly so you could distinguish the URL groups

Another option is plotting only those URLs which response time(s) is relatively high, you can get the numbers from [Aggregate Listeners](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-listeners-part-2-listeners-aggregate-data-samples) which display statistics only.

Once you have a list of URLs which you want to plot you can use [Filter Results Tool](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/FilterResultsTool/) to create a smaller .jtl file with only "interesting" data.